# Java GridBag Layout not working properly

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, gridbaglayout

I have two tables and two buttons. I want table-1 to be in the first column and as wide as 3 units, then I want the two buttons to the right of the table much more narrower (1 units in width), I want button one on the top and button2 on the bottom. Now to the right of these buttons I want the other table (table-2) again as wide as 3 units. To achieve this I have used the following constraints:

```
        //table1
        c = new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 3, 2, 1, 1,
                GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL,
                new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0);
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        outerPanel.add(all_app_scrollpane, c);

        //button1
        c = new GridBagConstraints(3, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL,
                new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0);
        outerPanel.add(addButton, c);

        //button2
        c = new GridBagConstraints(3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL,
                new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0);
        outerPanel.add(removeButton, c);

        //table2
        c = new GridBagConstraints(4, 0, 3, 2, 1, 1,
                GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL,
                new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0);
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        outerPanel.add(curr_app_scrollpane, c);
```

Let's look at the GridBagCOnstraints of table1. As far as I know, the first parameter states that it will start from the 0. column and will be 3 columns wide (third parameter).
And then button1 will start from the third column and will be one column wide. But I think I know something wrong as the result is very different then I expect.

[image]

I want these buttons much more narrower and tables much wider. How can I do that? I want to accomplish this using GridBag, as this small panel is just a small part of a very complex gui, and the whole gui is designed using gridbag. So I don't want to change the coding style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the grow settings (weightx) of the layout so that only the left and right column are growing.

Like this:

```
    contentPane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    ((GridBagLayout)contentPane.getLayout()).columnWidths = new int[] {0, 0, 0, 0};
    ((GridBagLayout)contentPane.getLayout()).rowHeights = new int[] {0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0};
    ((GridBagLayout)contentPane.getLayout()).columnWeights = new double[] {1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0E-4};
    ((GridBagLayout)contentPane.getLayout()).rowWeights = new double[] {1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0E-4};

    //---- leftBtn ----
    leftBtn.setText("left Button");
    contentPane.add(leftBtn, new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 1, 5, 0.0, 0.0,
        GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH,
        new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));

    //---- rightBtn ----
    rightBtn.setText("right Button");
    contentPane.add(rightBtn, new GridBagConstraints(2, 0, 1, 5, 0.0, 0.0,
        GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH,
        new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));

    //---- addBtn ----
    addBtn.setText("add Button");
    contentPane.add(addBtn, new GridBagConstraints(1, 1, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0,
        GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH,
        new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));

    //---- remBtn ----
    remBtn.setText("rem Button");
    contentPane.add(remBtn, new GridBagConstraints(1, 3, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0,
        GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH,
        new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
```

So it gives that:
[image: demo]

Greetings Florian

Edit: Here a Screenshot from the IDE, with additional space between the buttons: [image: demo2]

Comment: Your code generates a very different result and something very far from what I want. The first parameter of GridBagConstraints constructor is gridx, the third is gridwidth. In your code left button is on gridx 0 with the width of 1. add and rem buttons are on gridx1 with width 1. Right button is on gridx 2 with width 1. As a result I didn't achieve what I wanted.

Comment: here is a screenshot from the IDE, you can see I have added some rows to center the buttons and to create a gap between them

http://imgur.com/DHEMD

Comment: In your screenshot all buttons have the same width. What I want is to make the buttons in the middle narrower (less wider I mean)

Comment: NO I have seen them wrong. Sorry. I will look again to your code. Thanks for helping. I have misseen

Comment: you can just do the same as i did by the rows. Add some extra columns like that: https://imgur.com/8kFcY also set the buttons to `GridBagConstraints.CENTER`

Comment: Thanks for the help ((GridBagLayout)outerPanel.getLayout()).columnWidths = new int[] {0, 0, 0, 0};
((GridBagLayout)outerPanel.getLayout()).rowHeights = new int[] {0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0};
((GridBagLayout)outerPanel.getLayout()).columnWeights = new double[] {1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0E-4};
((GridBagLayout)outerPanel.getLayout()).rowWeights = new double[] {1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0E-4}; I have overlooked at these and didin't give them importance. But when I added these, I have done what I have wanted. Can you explain what these lines do?

Answer (score 3):

On button1 and button2, reduce their weightx to 0.0. Something like this:

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class Test4 {

    protected void initUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.weightx = 0.5;
        gbc.weighty = 1.0;
        gbc.gridheight = 2;
        panel.add(getTable(), gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 2;
        panel.add(getTable(), gbc);

        GridBagConstraints gbc2 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc2.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        gbc2.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        gbc2.gridx = 1;
        gbc2.weighty = 1.0;
        panel.add(new JButton("Button 1"), gbc2);
        gbc2.gridy = 1;
        panel.add(new JButton("Button 2"), gbc2);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private Component getTable() {
        Vector<Vector<String>> data = new Vector<Vector<String>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Vector<String> row = new Vector<String>();
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                row.add("Cell (" + i + "," + j + ")");
            }
            data.add(row);
        }
        Vector<String> columns = new Vector<String>();
        columns.add("Column 1");
        columns.add("Column 2");
        columns.add("Column 3");
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columns);
        JTable table = new JTable(model);
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
        scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        return scroll;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Test4().initUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

*Sorry for the constraint reuse, it is bad for readability.*